# QXmlStreamWriter and cyrillic

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have a problem with encoding when writing XML files via `QXmlStreamWriter` in windows, how can I resolve it? Using `stream.setCodec("UTF-8")` or "windows-1251" is not helped.

```
QFile *file = new QFile(filename);
if (file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
         {
         QXmlStreamWriter stream(file);
         stream.setAutoFormatting(true);
         stream.writeStartDocument();
         stream.writeStartElement("СЕКЦИЯ"); // start root section
            stream.writeStartElement("FIELD");
            stream.writeAttribute("name", "Имя");
            stream.writeAttribute("value", "Иван");
            stream.writeEndElement();
         stream.writeEndElement(); // END СЕКЦИЯ
         file->close();
}
```

Comment: `stream.writeEndDocument()` is missed and I would open the file binary (`file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)`).

Comment: It's sample code, I've succ working code, but problem in encode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the interpretation of the string literals in your source file is the problem, not the configuration of the stream writer.
Make sure your source file is encoded in UTF-8 and use QString::fromUtf8("Imja") etc. (Imja in cyrillic of course) instead of the implicit literal to QString conversion.